# gitlab clone fails with could not read from remote repository

Tags: gitlab

While trying to clone a repository from gitlab, I ran into the following error:

```
git clone <USER>@<URL>:<path_to_project.git>
Cloning into 'xxx'...
<USER>@<URL>'s password: 
fatal: 'root/acl-labl-website.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I tried both the SSL and HTTP address, and both got this similar error. Not sure what it meant, and after many tries involving modifying config files (from gitlab, nginx, apache checking redirects, etc.), I found the very simple answer. Still not sure why my other method didn't work, but I found that first adding your public ssh key to gitlab (through the GUI), then using the same command as above, but using git instead of my username:

```
git clone git@<URL>:<repo_path>.git
```

worked. I.e. generate your id_rsa.pub as explained here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html , copy this to your ssh keys (which in my case was one of the tabs in the gitlab GUI; I've done this before for git as well, where it's also to be found somewhere in your user settings). In my case I had to run

```
ssh-add
```

still before it worked, but with a colleague it worked without as well. 
Then the cloning using git@ instead of username@ worked perfectly. Again; still not sure why it won't work using my username and password (same as the one I use to login to the gitlab GUI), so if someone could shed some light on that, I'd be interested in it. But since it took my quite some time before I found this solution/work-around, thought I'd post it here. Perhaps better suited to serverfault actually, but since I suspect many people end up here as well, perhaps the admins can live with this post here :)